# Powershell ConverFrom-JSON nested parsing

Tags: json, powershell

The following code gives me some output, but I am struggling to get a list of just the IDs from projectGroups

```
$uri = 'https://projects.brand.com/data/folder/8133'

wget $uri -UseDefaultCredentials |
ConvertFrom-JSON |

Select projectGroups
```

This yields an output as follows

```
{@{id=44068; uuid=959844e7-5bfc-45f9-9a87-54bc6384dbab; name=projects; createdAt=2016-10-06T20:33:05; createdBy=user1; lastUpdatedAt=2017-02-14T18:30:45; lastUpdatedBy=user2; projectId=; f...
```

What I have so far I have pieced together from the googles, but I am not sure how to formulate the rest of the code to give me a foreach list of the id=##### under the projectGroups.

I need that because I then have to take each of those projectids and use them in another URL https://projects.brand.com/data/project/export/projects-tasks?projectIds[]=`<projectid1>`&projectIds[]=`<projectid2>`

How can I add to the above code to either create an array of projectids from the projectsGroup and inject it back as a foreach into the URL or even just inject it directly into the url?

Edit:

Based on the code in the answer I have the following:

```
$pid = @()
$uri = "https://projects.brand.com/data/folder/"
$projectUri = $uri + "8133"
$aJsonObj = wget $projectUri -UseDefaultCredentials | ConvertFrom-JSON
$projectGroups = $aJsonObj.projectGroups
foreach ( $id in $projectGroups.projectId ) {
    $nextProjectUri = $uri + $id
    $anotherJsonObj = wget $nextProjectUri -UseDefaultCredentials | ConvertFrom-JSON
    $pid = $pid + $id
}

Out-Host $pid
```

That is giving me a Cannot overwrite variable error for the array.  I feel like that code isn't going to get the id for each of the projects in that folder either though.  The URI shouldn't change during the foreach loop I don't think.  It should just loop through each of the id's from the original URI and push them into an array.

Edit 2:

```
$uri = 'https://projects.brand.com/data/folder/8133'
$pid = @()
$projectids = wget $uri -UseDefaultCredentials |
ConvertFrom-JSON | Select projectGroups | select -Expand projectGroups | select id 
Write-Host $projectids

foreach($id in $projectids) {    
    $pid += $id
    }

Write-Host $pid
```

This gives me a list, but it shows @{id=#####} when I do it.  This feels closer to what I need than the previous code.  pid is still throwing a read-only or constant error.

Comment: Can you add another ` | Select -Expand projectID`?

Comment: Select projectGroups | select -Expand projectGroups | select id

okay that gives me a list, now I just have to figure out how to put that in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a bit harder than I thought; I finally found something that helped after you guys pointed me in the right direction.  I have edited with the final code piece that I am using.

It loops through the root folder to find all the child folders and then it loops through the project Ids within those child folders. The code is only built to go two levels deep and it's probably not as efficient and clean as an experienced coder would make, but here it is.

```
function Get-Data(){
    #set the root folder
    $uri1 = 'https://project.brand.com/data/folder/8133'
    [PSObject[]] $fid = @()
    [PSObject[]] $pid = @()

    $folderIds = wget $uri1 -UseDefaultCredentials |
    ConvertFrom-JSON | select children | select -Expand children | select id

    #get all the sub-folder ids
    ForEach-Object{    
        [PSObject[]]$fid += $folderIds.id
    }

    #use the folder ids to loop through and retreive all project ids in subfolders
    for($i = 0 ; $i -ne ($fid.length); $i++){

        $uri2 = 'https://projects.brand.com/data/project/folder/'
        $getUri1 = $uri2 + [PSObject[]]$fid[$i]
        $projectIds = wget $getUri1 -UseDefaultCredentials |
        ConvertFrom-JSON | Select data | select -Expand data | select id

        #obtain all the project ids
        ForEach-Object{    
            [PSObject[]]$pid += $projectIds.id
        }

        $uri3 = "https://projects.brand.com/data/project/export/projects-tasks?projectIds[]="
        $getIds = [PSObject[]]$pid -join "&projectIds[]=" 
        $getUri2 = $uri3 + $getIds
        $of = "\\domain\dept\DI\Extracts\Projects Tasks " + $i + ".xlsx"

        #retrieve excel files of tasks from each sub-folder
        wget $getUri2 -outfile $of -UseDefaultCredentials

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't validate it works, but something like this:

```
$uri = "https://projects.brand.com/data/folder/"
$projectUri = $uri + "8133"
$aJsonObj = wget $projectUri -UseDefaultCredentials | ConvertFrom-JSON
$projectGroups = $aJsonObj.projectGroups
foreach ( $id in $projectGroups.projectId ) {
    $nextProjectUri = $uri + $id
    $anotherJsonObj = wget $nextProjectUri -UseDefaultCredentials | ConvertFrom-JSON
    # do something with it....
}
```